# How to judge a budget hotel's safety standards?

Tags: safety, hotels, security, southeast-asia, natural-disasters

I will be staying at a budget hotel in southeast asia soon, I'd like to know how I can find out either beforehand or when I arrive if the hotel's safety standards are good, i.e. what to look for when 'inspecting' the hotel.

Having watched many Hotel Impossible episodes, I know that many budget hotels neglect guest safety either through deliberate negligence or incompetence. I'm especially concerned because safety standards in southeast asian countries are poorer in general (maybe except for singapore).

I'd like to judge the safety in case of a fire (like how to tell if the curtain in the room is fire-retardant or not), natural disasters, and general security against criminals.

Comment: I would not restrict this to budget hotels. Check if there are smoke detectors, see if fire escape routes are signaled and unobstructed and check all possible entrances for safety against criminals. Not sure what you mean by natural disasters here?

Comment: I mean natural disasters like an earthquake

Comment: Hotel Impossible is a TV show, it over-dramatize issues for the sake of entertainment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**beforehand**

- read reviews and search them for your keywords, e.g. "fire alarm", "escape routes", ...
- check the hotel website for information on the property and make your own guesses. I would be more concerned about earthquakes in a high-rise hotel than in a wooden bungalow on the beach, whereas in the latter a tsunami might frighten you more

**at the hotel: fire**

- upon check-in inquire with the receptionist about safety standards and precautions. this might not change anything for you but maybe make them more sensitive in the long run. it'll also give you a first idea
- check if there are smoke detectors, request to have a room with a working smoke detector if possible
- check escape routes on the floor plan and do walk them, make sure they are unobstructed, easy to find, and well-signaled even in the dark. report any objections you may find to management and request to have a room with an easy escape path.

**at the hotel: theft and burglary**

- do check the in-room safe (if existing) on how much you would trust it, check the doors and windows and other possible entrances on how easy it is to get. act accordingly
- don't have valuables with you on the trip or do store them safely

And in general, don't overthink it, in most of the cases things go smoothly, you do often get what you pay for but I've had great stays in simple huts in the jungle, and have a good trip.